# Use Java MVEL to Compare Expressions

Tags: java, boolean-expression, mvel

Is it possible to use java MVEL library to determine if one boolean expression is covered by another boolean expression? Here boolean expression A is 'covered' by boolean expression B if whatever value that satisfies B will surely satisfy A. For example, if expression A is "x >= 1 && x <= 100" and expression B is "x >=25 && x <= 50", then any value of x that satisfies B will also satisfy A, and, therefore, A is covered by B.

Thanks in advance.